# How to add new widgets between spacers in a QGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

Given this form:

[image]

How I could add some buttons **between** the `horizontalSpacers` at the bottom?

```
// slideshow.h
void SlideShow::addImage(QPixmap pixmap)
{
    //...
    int index = slideButtons.size();

    SlideButton* btn = new SlideButton(this);
    slideButtons.insert(index, btn);

    gridLayout->addWidget(btn, 2, index + 1);
}
```

---

```
#include "slideshow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    ui.slideShow->gridLayout = ui.gridLayout;
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet1.png"));
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet2.png"));
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet3.png"));
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet4.png"));
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet5.png"));
}
```

Result:

[image]

Only the first button get in the middle, and its also moving the `slideShow` widget to the left.

I'm confused about how to proper add the positions in the layout, to be more precise here:

```
gridLayout->addWidget(btn, 2, index + 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt Designer, between your two spacers, put a QFrame, and give it a QHBoxLayout.

And then, in your code

```
#include "slideshow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    ui.slideShow->buttonsHorizLayout = ui.horizLayout;
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet1.png"));
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet2.png"));
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet3.png"));
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet4.png"));
    ui.slideShow->addImage(QPixmap("D:/pictures/pet5.png"));
}
```

```
// slideshow.h
void SlideShow::addImage(const QPixmap &pixmap)
{
    //...
    int index = slideButtons.size();

    SlideButton* btn = new SlideButton(pixmap,this);
    slideButtons.insert(index, btn);

    buttonsHorizLayout->insertWidget(index,btn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i would like to understand what was wrong in my previous code, and why the buttons are added to the layout like that.